# Importing data from Excel sheet to DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I am having a problem importing data from Excel sheet to a Amazon DynamoDB table. I have the Excel sheet in an Amazon S3 bucket and I want to import data from this sheet to a table in DynamoDB.

Currently I am following [Import and Export DynamoDB Data Using AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html) but my pipeline is not working normally.

It gives me `WAITING_FOR_RUNNER` status and after sometime the status changed to `CANCELED`. Please suggest what I am doing wrong or is there any other way to import data from an Excel sheet to a DynamoDB table?

Comment: How about using a tool like [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com/features/dynamodb_import_tool.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The potential reasons are as follows:-

**Reason 1:**

> If your pipeline is in the SCHEDULED state and one or more tasks
>   appear stuck in the WAITING_FOR_RUNNER state, ensure that you set a
>   valid value for either the runsOn or workerGroup fields for those
>   tasks. If both values are empty or missing, the task cannot start
>   because there is no association between the task and a worker to
>   perform the tasks. In this situation, you've defined work but haven't
>   defined what computer will do that work. If applicable, verify that
>   the workerGroup value assigned to the pipeline component is exactly
>   the same name and case as the workerGroup value that you configured
>   for Task Runner.

**Reason 2:-**

> Another potential cause of this problem is that the endpoint and
>   access key provided to Task Runner is not the same as the AWS Data
>   Pipeline console or the computer where the AWS Data Pipeline CLI tools
>   are installed. You might have created new pipelines with no visible
>   errors, but Task Runner polls the wrong location due to the difference
>   in credentials, or polls the correct location with insufficient
>   permissions to identify and run the work specified by the pipeline
>   definition.